# Left Alt on my macbook pro decided to be Right Alt. How do I fix it?

Tags: macos

Left Alt is used for various shortcuts, Right Alt for diacritical characters. For some reason Left Alt started working as Right Alt, producing diacritical characters, so I have no way to use any shortcuts involving Alt/Option key.

Any idea what might be causing it and how to fix it? It worked just fine a few hours ago, and it didn't get fixed by a restart.

Comment: Why do you have an "osx" tag on this? OS X doesn't differentiate between the two option keys. Between that and you calling it "Alt", I think you must be talking about Windows or some other OS, not OS X.

Comment: @Spiff Actually, different Apple keyboards label that key either Opt or Alt - but the rest of it sure sounds like Windows to me.

Comment: @Tetsujin The key has always been called Option in Mac OS. On they keyboard, it was eventually given a secondary label of "Alt" for people running emulators, VMs, or Boot Camp.

Comment: @Spiff - my last 2 keyboards only say alt [one from 08 & one from last year]. Checking Google images, it would appear the UK keyboard says alt, the US says opt, some in full as option with alt written above.